# Solr-MySQL DataImportHandler only retrieves ID instead of SELECT * query

Tags: mysql, solr, search-engine, dataimporthandler

I'm new to SEO and having an issue with Mysql data extraction within Solr 8.8; despite that below declaration, the document is only retrieving ID instead of the whole bunch.

```
<document>
  <entity name="foobars"
    query="SELECT *, 'test' AS ENTITY FROM foobar"
    deltaquery="SELECT ID FROM foobar WHERE updated >= '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
    deltaimportquery="SELECT *, 'MAT' AS ENTITY FROM foobar WHERE ID = ${dataimporter.delta.id}">
    <field column="ENTITY" name="entity" />
    <field column="ID" name="id" />
    <field column="FOO" name="foo" />
    <field column="BAR" name="bar" />
    <field column="BAZ" name="baz" />
    <field column="UPDATED" name="updated" />  
  </entity>
</document>
```

This is a sample of what was imported :

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":9,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "_":"1623166185835"}},
  "response":{"numFound":147,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"214768.0",
        "_version_":1702016739810738176},
      {
        "id":"296594.0",
        "_version_":1702016739840098304},
...
```

Does anyone knows what I'm missing here? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does your schema look like? Do you have the fields defined already?

Comment: @MatsLindh I'm going schemaless at this stage. I didn't think that would be the issue, since this mode was made such a deal in the examples I found.

Comment: @MatsLindh ... but it sure did the trick, though. So I'm a bit confused : what is the schemaless mode about ??

Comment: It's about using Solr by making Solr guess on the formats. However, DIH is old (and deprecated - it has been removed from Solr core in 9.0) and was written when there was no schemaless mode. The schema guessing happens after DIH has processed the rows, but DIH uses the schema to decide which fields to include and map (in its entities). So unless something has changed recently, DIH requires a defined schema. You should always define a schema when running in production anyway; the schemaless mode is neat for prototyping things quickly.

Comment: Thank you very much @MatsLindh do you know what DIH's alternative is or will be?

Comment: You can still get DIH from an external resource and add it to your project if you need to. But in most cases you'll just create a small import application in your programming language of choice and input data with a regular Solr client. It'll be far more efficient as it allows you to use the whole cluster for importing data (and not just a single node). You'll also have a full programming language at your disposal to transform data when being imported. An SQL statement combined with a Solr client will be 10-15 lines in most languages.

Comment: Thx again @MatsLindh do you have any experience concerning the efficiency of massive external imports as you just described? I'm very concerned about initial or full imports over HTTP...

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of factors you think about with "massive external imports", but imports in the 100M <-> 1B range isn't an issue at least. Make sure you batch many documents together in each update - do _not_ send a single update for each document. Use `commitWithin` or issue a commit at the end of your import - i.e. commit as seldom as possible. Use multiple threads, and if you have a cluster, use a cluster-aware-client or manually distribute the indexing load to multiple servers.

Comment: I really appreciate your insight @MatsLindh have a good day